# How to download geology data for Argentina and Chile

Tags: data-request, chile, argentina

I found on the OneGeology website geology layers for Argentina and Chile but am unsure how to donwload them. http://portal.onegeology.org/OnegeologyGlobal/

Chile's data source http://www.sernageomin.cl/
Argentina's data source http://www.segemar.gov.ar/

And nowhere on either of their data source websites I can find a place to download the digital data. Can anyone find a way to get access to this data?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sources for all of those data sources is down:

You can get the details on OneGeology's information through the data catalogue:

http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/catalog.search#/home

Here are pages for Chile and Argentina.

http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?fast=index&_content_type=json&from=1&to=20&sortBy=relevance&keyword=Chile

http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?fast=index&_content_type=json&from=1&to=20&sortBy=relevance&keyword=Argentina

Comment: That's a shame, thank you for having a more in depth look for me though